# How to view files from host? (running inside VMWare Fusion)

Tags: vmware

I have just finished moving my development server into a Ubuntu 10.04 Server VM in VMWare Fusion 3.  I have all of my mysql and tomcat stuff running and am now trying to connect to my actual site files which are stored on my mac under `/{User Root}/Workspace/ColdFusion/`.

I know that normally you should be able to setup a shared folder in VMWare and find it under `/mnt/hgfs/{Share Name}`, but I can't find it.  I am not sure if I have to manually mount it or what.

Answer (score 1):

[This question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24149/sharing-directories-are-not-shown) from prosseek might help you.  The `sshfs` method seems a bit unorthodox to me, but I don't have vmware-fusion available to test any other way.