# Sharing directories are not shown

Tags: vmware

I use Ubuntu on my Mac with VMWare Fusion.
I setup share folders.

[image]

However, I don't have anything in /mnt/hgfs

[image]

I did have the shared directories, but they're not there.
What's wrong with this, and how can I link them back again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reinstalled the 'vmware tools' (Virtual Machine -> Install VMWare tools', and it's working now.

I remember the menu was 'Update VMWare tools', but I found it changed to 'Install VMWare tools' when I had the trouble.

### ADDED

I could use sshfs to access the directories in ubuntu.

1. Install sshfs `sudo port install sshfs` in Mac
2. Create the directory in Mac `mkdir ~/mnt/ubuntu`
3. Link the network directory to the directory that you created `sshfs user@ip:DIRECTORY ~/mnt/ubuntu`